# Xdebug module missing in phpinfo() on El Capitan

Tags: php, xdebug, osx-elcapitan

I have trouble with xdebug i've installed the via brew for the 5.5 version.The xdebug module didnt appear on phpinfo(); neither in zend powered.
But when i do php -i the module appears. Some got an idea why?
Thank a lot.

Comment: php has more than one .ini file, have you edited both or just the cli one? you can see which is being loaded in the phpinfo() output

Comment: I got /etc  for Configuration File (php.ini) Path but its .ini.default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok simple rename php.ini.default loaded by phpinfo to php.ini